# Format date from dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss Angular JS / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, format

As the question says, how would I best format a string from:

```
`dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss`
```

to

```
yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss
```

For example:

This `27/01/2015 10:00:00`

To this: `2015/01/27 10:00:00`

Up to now I have tried: `$filter('date')("27/01/2015 10:00:00", "yyyy/MM/dd/ HH:mm:ss'");`

Ideally this would be in AngularJS using either `$filter` or as an expression `{{ expression || filter }}` but plain JS will do

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a forum to request others write your code for you.

Comment: I have tried: `$filter('date')("27/01/2015 10:00:00", "yyyy/MM/dd/ HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '(EDT)'");` but I assume I am doing it wrong as the dates are not changing.

Comment: Well, for starters your format string is missing a closing quotation mark.

Comment: @Stef Sorry, that was just a mistake when typing in here. I have changed it.

Comment: @Alan Gotcha. What's going on with your timezone string? Are you trying to get the offset between GMT and EDT?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter from AngularJS:

```
var date = new Date();
$filter('date')(date, 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss');
```

Comment: I need it for specific dates. Not a `new Date()`

Comment: You need to convert your string into a date before using `date`filter

Comment: This is why I need to re format the date as `dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss` is not in the correct format for `new Date()`

Comment: No way with Angular without moment>

Comment: Yes parse the string to be as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`